# Windows 8.1 Store apps doesn't restore correctly if minimized and maximized from taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-store-app

When there is a minimized full screen app on my taskbar if i try to maximize it again, most of the pictures and layout elements doesn't load. For example on a music app (int the same situation) i have to guess where was the pause button because it is not there anymore. But when i click to the right place, somehow it loads and becomes visible. Is this some kind of caching (app) problem or my systems problem?

Comment: You didn't say which music app, but from experience, Cubase will do that if it's really struggling for RAM. It's not too much of an intuitive leap to guess that might be your underlying issue; not enough RAM, too much paging.  More detailed question would give more accurate answer.

Comment: Because i don't expect this to be a specific app problem. If you want names, i face this problem on karnaval.com app(local music app), Spotlite App, Radyo app. I am only using music apps from Windows Store so this is a very general problem i face. That's why i didn't point specific apps. I have no idea how Facebook's or Twitter's Windows Store app behaves on same situation.

Comment: Also memory load is not the case for my system. Because i have 8gb ram with %40 load and the problem still persists.

Comment: More detailed question would give more accurate answer... Precisely what OS, RAM, Graphics, Drivers... also, windows will start to page long before it's really using a high percentage of system RAM, so HD type, HD, SSD etc... which other apps running, esp browsers, which can use a lot of RAM for child processes... etc, etc, etc

Comment: Are you kidding me? Do you even read what i wrote? Ofcourse i am talking about Windows 8.1 OS and Windows Store apps. We are not doing rocket science here. What does my HDD, SSD or Graphics card has to do with a common music app. I am not rendering anything. Also i can't imagine a freshly booted Windows, plus a Windows Store music app filling the 8gigs memory.